# read strings from txt file and stop at first line in c++

Tags: c++, stack, queue, palindrome, istringstream

I have to use stack and queue to check if it is palindrome from the txt file for my homework.

************Txt File**************

Did I say you never say "never say never"? You say I did.

Did I say you never say "never"?

Are you glad you are king?

King, are you glad you are king?

Fall leaves after leaves fall.

Says Mom, "What do you do?" -You do what Mom says.

Says Mom, "What do you do?" -You do what Mom does.

You know, I did little for you, for little did I know you.

You know, I did little for you, since little did I know you.

First Ladies rule the State.

Escher, drawing hands, drew hands drawing.

You can cage a swallow, can't you?

First Ladies rule the State, and state the rule: "ladies first".

Blessed are they that believe they are blessed.

You can cage a swallow, can't you, but you can't swallow a cage, can you?

Mind your own business: Own your mind.

Rode, and rode, and rode, and rode, and rode, and rode, and rode!

Clatter and hum and crunch, and crunch and hum and clatter.

Mind your own business.

All for one, and one for all!

Escher, drawing hands, drew hands drawing Escher.

---

pretend there is no empty space between each lines.
So, after the first line, there is no empty line, the second sentence follows.

I used istringstream to stop at first line, but there is an error with the output. The last word of each sentence print out twice for some reason.

Here is my code,

```
void getData(Stack<string> &s, Queue<string> &q)
{
    ifstream readFile;
    string temp;
    string temp1;
    Stack<string> a[24];
    Queue<string> b[24];
    int j = 0;
    //int b = 0;

readFile.open("test_word_plndrms.txt");

if(!readFile)
{
    cout << "Error opening the file" << endl;
    exit(1);
}
else {
    while(!readFile.eof()) {
            getline(readFile, temp);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < temp.length(); ++i) {
                if (ispunct(temp[i]))
                    temp.erase(i--, 1);
                if(isupper(temp[i]))
                    temp[i] = tolower(temp[i]);
            }
        istringstream ss(temp);
            while(ss) {
                ss >> temp1;
                cout << temp1 << endl;
                a[j].push(temp1);
                b[j].enqueue(temp1);
            }
        j++;

    }

}
```

}

And this is my output,

did
i
say
you
never
say
never
say
never
you
say
i
did
did
did
i
say
you
never
say
never
never
are
you
glad
you
are
king
king
king
are
you
glad
you
are
king
king
fall
leaves
after
leaves
fall
fall
says
mom
what
do
you
do
you
do
what
mom
says
says
says
mom
what
do
you
do
you
do
what
mom
does
does
you
know
i
did
little
for
you
for
little
did
i
know
you
you
you
know
i
did
little
for
you
since
little
did
i
know
you
you
first
ladies
rule
the
state
state
escher
drawing
hands
drew
hands
drawing
drawing
you
can
cage
a
swallow
cant
you
you
first
ladies
rule
the
state
and
state
the
rule
ladies
first
first
blessed
are
they
that
believe
they
are
blessed
blessed
you
can
cage
a
swallow
cant
you
but
you
cant
swallow
a
cage
can
you
you
mind
your
own
business
own
your
mind
mind
rode
and
rode
and
rode
and
rode
and
rode
and
rode
and
rode
rode
clatter
and
hum
and
crunch
and
crunch
and
hum
and
clatter
clatter
mind
your
own
business
business
all
for
one
and
one
for
all
all
escher
drawing
hands
drew
hands
drawing
escher
escher
Program ended with exit code: 0

What I am trying to do is read the first line, and put each word such as "did" "i" "say" "you" "never" "say" "never" "say" "never" "you" "say" "i" "did" and push them to stack and queue.
And then, pop each strings and if popped string is different, it is not a palindrome sentence, if it is all same, it is a palindrome sentence.

Can someone give me any suggestion for this homework? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it prints the last word twice is because of the statement:

```
while(ss)
{
   ...
}
```

The while loop takes an extra loop because ss is still valid.
You can probably clear it and check if temp1 is empty.

```
while (ss)
{
    ss >> temp1;

    if (temp1.empty())
    {
        break;
    }

    cout << temp1 << endl;
    a[j].push(temp1);
    b[j].enqueue(temp1);
    temp1.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop executed an extra loop since it was erroneously checking if there exists a CURRENT word (which had already been printed in the previous loop). It should be checking if there exists a NEXT word to be printed. I have thus changed the condition for the `while` loop.

```
void getData (Stack<string> &s, Queue<string> &q) {

    ifstream readFile;
    string temp;
    string temp1;
    Stack<string> a[24];
    Queue<string> b[24];
    int j = 0;

    readFile.open("test_word_plndrms.txt");

    if (!readFile) {
        cout << "Error opening the file" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Reading file" << endl << endl;
        while (!readFile.eof()) {
            getline(readFile, temp);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < temp.length(); ++i) {
                if (ispunct(temp[i])) {
                    temp.erase(i--, 1);
                }
                if (isupper(temp[i])) {
                    temp[i] = tolower(temp[i]);
                }
            }
            cout << "Finished reading line #" << j+1 << ":" << endl;
            istringstream ss(temp);

            while (ss.peek() != EOF) {
                ss >> temp1;
                cout << temp1 << ' ';
                a[j].push(temp1);
                b[j].enqueue(temp1);
            }
            cout << endl << endl;
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```